# Emacs dired: how to display nested directories?

Tags: emacs, dired

When I do `i` on a directory in Emacs dired, a new block of lines for that directory is appended to the buffer.  Can I display the subdirectory inline, instead?

Or maybe there is a different package that does something similar?

This is what I get today (slightly edited):

```
  /tmp/foo:
  total used in directory 1 available 9788168
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32 a
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32 b
  drwxr-xr-x  4 jrl wheel 136 Sep 16 22:32 bar

  /tmp/foo/bar:
  total used in directory 1 available 9788168
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32 one
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32 two
```

This is what I might want:

```
  /tmp/foo:
  total used in directory 1 available 9788168
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32 a
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32 b
  drwxr-xr-x  4 jrl wheel 136 Sep 16 22:32 bar
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32 bar/one
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32 bar/two
```

Or maybe this:

```
  /tmp/foo:
  total used in directory 1 available 9788168
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32 a
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32 b
  drwxr-xr-x  4 jrl wheel 136 Sep 16 22:32 bar
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32   •/one
  -rw-r--r--  1 jrl wheel   0 Sep 16 22:32   •/two
```

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to do this -- e.g., no package that does it. It would be a fair amount of work for you to try to code it up.  Not worth trying, IMHO.

My advice is to get used to using `i` (command `dired-maybe-insert-subdir`). You can do a lot with inserted subdirectories.

IOW, learn first to use what Dired already offers -- it's your friend.

Comment: Well, `M-x find-dired` already knows the first of the output formats I proposed, so the only action here is to get this stuff inserted into the buffer.